# Фильтр списка в списке

Tags: c#, .net, linq

У меня есть список под названием matrix. Каждый элемент в matrix содержит еще один список под названием Items. 
Я хочу выбрать все элементы из Items, где свойство Items.Type == true. Как это можно реализовать с помощью Linq?

Comment: перебором списка и обращение к его Items типа foreach(var mitems in matrix){ mitems.FindOrDefault(x => x.Type == true)} код для примера не кидайтесь камнями )))

Answer (score 3):

Можно попробовать использовать SelectMany.

Например, есть класс

```
class Item
{
    public bool Type {get;set;}
}
```

Тогда коллекция будет

```
var matrix = new List<List<Item>>() { new List<Item>() { 
        new Item() { Type = true }, 
        new Item() { Type = false } } };
```

Выборка

```
var items = matrix.SelectMany(x=>x).Where(x=>x.Type == true).ToList();
```

Comment: Аж приятно читать, спасибо))))

Comment: @Dude36 на здоровье :)